# Мне нужно считать из файла

Tags: lua

Мне нужно считать из файла и записать в str все что было в файле. В файле у меня текст. Я написала функцию и хотела проверить работает ли она. И она не работает. нужна ваша помощь

```
local str = "";
function ReadFile(filename)
  local file = io.open(filename, "r")
  if file == nil then
    return false;
  else
    str = file:read("*all")
    file:close();
    return true;
  end

end

ReadFile("C:/Users/Desktop/str.txt")

 for i = 1, #str do
    print(str[i])
end
```

Выводится такое:

```
nil
nil
nil
nil
nil
nil
nil
nil
nil
nil
nil
nil
nil
nil
nil
nil
nil
nil
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы используете неверный формат, да ещё и неверно итерируетесь по строке.
Строки в языке луа не поддерживают индексацию через оператор
`[]`.  Вот рабочий код:

```lua
function readfile(filename)
  local file = io.open(filename, "r")
  if file == nil then
    return
  end

  local str = file:read("a")
  file:close()

  return str
end

local str = readfile([[C:\Users\Oksana\Desktop\str.txt]])

print(str)
```

А индексирование по строке делается через метод `sub`:

```lua
for i = 1, #str do
  print(str:sub(i, i))
end
```

Comment: у меня файл  на рабочем столе. Когда я так  пишу:  local str = ReadFile("C:/Users/Desktop/str.txt") оно выдает ошибку:   attempt to call global 'ReadFile' (a nil value)

Comment: @oksanavovl  Обратите внимание на имя, которое я дал функции.  В языке луа не принято использовать «КамелКейс».  См. [гид по стилю](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaStyleGuide).

Comment: @ok. сделала с маленькой. Но как правильно путь  записать?

Comment: @oksanavovl  См. правку.  Для путей _Windows_ лучше использовать нотацию «неформатированных» строк.  В пути я указал ваш `%username%` как `Oksana`, вам нужно заменить это на настоящее имя вашего пользователя в ОС.

Comment: странно. я вынесла в корень файл - local str = readFile([[D:/str.txt]]) но таже ошибка.. файл не пустой....

Comment: @oksanavovl  Что за ошибка-то?  Будьте яснее.  Пробуйте открыть файл в `cmd.exe`.